# Suggestions for handling Arbitrary-precision arithmetic in Apple Swift language?

Tags: swift, arbitrary-precision, integer-arithmetic

I'm about to write my own BigInt/BigDecimal (like in Java) class to be used in a number of Swift projects.
From the Wikipedia topic on Arbitrary-precision arithmetic I found an overview of some interesting libraries, most of them C/C++ based. The following libraries seem useful to me: GNU Multi-Precision Library (GMP), MAPM, libgcrypt and OpenSSL.
Anybody experience with integrating C/C++ libraries in Xcode/Swift or is it better to convert/translate (which is my preferred way) them to Swift code?
In another Stackoverflow thread I see that GMP is mentioned very often, so do you think thats my best bet?

Comment: Best not to "is it better to convert/translate (which is my preferred way)" unless there is some really good test code available. Better to just create a SWIFT swapper around a working "C" library.

Comment: Agreed @Zaph, and I may be wasting my time since C-integration should not be that difficult after all? Currently I already managed to get the latest gmp-6.0.0a compiled and working using terminal commands. Next steps would be to integrate/link from it within an Xcode project (never done that before yet).

Comment: Here is one from scratch https://gist.github.com/JadenGeller/f469776b12fed2d84d6c